# How to display a list in a .JSP file?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl, resultset

After an hour of solid research I still can't do this.

This is my Servlet code:

```
package com.fdm.ProjectWeb.RedirectServlets;

import java.awt.List;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.naming.spi.DirStateFactory.Result;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.sql.ResultSupport;

import com.fdm.ProjectWeb.Controller.ValidateRegisterInputController;
import com.fdm.ProjectWeb.Model.OraclePullListOfUsers;
import com.fdm.ProjectWeb.Model.OracleUserManagement;

public class VerifyRedirect extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException, ServletException{
        OraclePullListOfUsers pull = new OraclePullListOfUsers();
        ResultSet rs = pull.unverifiedUsers();
        List list = new List();

    try {
        while (rs.next()){
            list.add(rs.getString(1));
    }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        req.setAttribute("list", list);
        RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("./WEB-INF/VerifyUser.jsp");
        rd.forward(req, resp);
    }
}
```

And this is my .JSP code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Verify Users</title>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <c:forEach items="${list}" var="item">
    <tr>
      <td><c:out value="${item}" /></td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</table>

    <h2>Please enter the Username of the user you want to verify</h2>
    <form action="loginform" method="POST">
        <label>User To Verify: <input type="text" name="userToVerify" id="userToVerify" /></label><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
    </form>

</body>
```

The Result Set definitely has data in it as if I system.out.println in the while loop it shows all the right values.

And I get this error message:

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in &lt;forEach&gt;
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Display List Contents in tabular format in a JSP file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646347/how-to-display-list-contents-in-tabular-format-in-a-jsp-file)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in <forEach>

This exception occur when your `<c:forEach items>` does not refer to an *Object*, that can be iterated upon. The *Object* should either be `Iterable`, a `Map`, or an *array*.
So clearly, your *list* attribute refers to the type which does not come under any of the above category. Though the type is actually a `List`, but not `java.util.List`.

Check your import statement:

```
import java.awt.List;   // Here is the fault
```

It should be:

```
import java.util.List;
```

Also, you should use generic type `List` instead of raw type. Change:

```
List list = new List();
```

to:

```
List<String> list = new List<String>();
```

---

Also, it seems like you are doing the *pre-processing* task in `doPost()` method. Don't. [`doPost()` is used for *post-processing* a request](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info). You should use `doget()` method for *pre-processing*.

Move all your code in `doPost()` to `doGet()` method.

Comment: Thanks a lot man (and to everyone else). Especially for the doGet tip :)

Comment: One more quick question!

What if I want to send the information the user entered as a parameter to another servlet - do I still use doGet() instead of doPost()

I'm reading the page you reccommend as we speak!

Comment: @oOTesterOo. No, that is what we call post-processing a request. We use `doPost` for that.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
List list = new List();
```

To:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

From

```
java.util.List;
```

Answer (score 1):

try instantiating the list like this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

or if it does not help maybe supply the list as an array such as:

```
req.setAttribute("list", list.toArray());
```